# Break the branch link for individual files in TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, merge, branch

When we create a branch from our main trunk in TFS we also change the web.config to point to different databases, web services, etc. When we make a bug fix we do it in the release branch and merge back to the trunk. I'd like a way to click on the root node for the branch and merge the whole thing back to the trunk *except* for the web.config which has release-branch-specific settings which should not be merged back.

Is there a way to break the branch link for this file or is there some other method to permanently exclude the release web.config when merging back to the trunk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options to do this today:

1. Use "tf merge /discard".  When performed on a file across branches it tells the merge engine that you do not want this specific change merged between these two branches.  The downside of this approach is that you will need to run tf merge /discard each time you check in a change to the file.  Here is what the syntax would look like if you wanted to discard the change from moving from releasebranch to trunk:

   tf merge $/releasebranch/.../web.config $/trunk/.../web.config /discard
2. The second option is to cloak the web.config in the target branch when you are performing the merge.  That is if you are merging into trunk, cloak the web.config file in the trunk branch in your workspace.  When you perform the merge, since the target of the merge is cloaked, the change will not flow over the branch.  The downside here of course is that you have to remember to perform the merges in workspaces with this configuration each time.

Bonus: I created this [uservoice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3132354-allow-developers-to-indicate-that-certain-files-sh) to improve this experience.  Vote for it if this is something you would like to see improved.

Comment: You might consider using transforms as well instead of the cloaking option.